# Stripping MS Word Tags Using Html Agility Pack

Tags: .net, html, html-agility-pack, strip

I have a DB with some text fields pasted from MS Word, and I'm having trouble to strip just the ,  and  tags, but obviously keeping their innerText.

I've tried using the HAP but I'm not going in the right direction..

```
Public Function StripHtml(ByVal html As String, ByVal allowHarmlessTags As Boolean) As String
    Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlDocument()
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html)
    Dim invalidNodes As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div|//font|//span")
    For Each node In invalidNodes
        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node, False)
    Next
    Return htmlDoc.DocumentNode.WriteTo()
End Function
```

This code simply selects the desired elements and removes them... but not keeping their  inner text..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I think I found a solution:

```
Public Function StripHtml(ByVal html As String) As String
    Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlDocument()
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html)
    Dim invalidNodes As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div|//font|//span|//p")
    For Each node In invalidNodes
        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node, True)
    Next
    Return htmlDoc.DocumentNode.WriteContentTo
End Function
```

I was almost there... :P